# The mathematical notation for a subset with given conditions

Tags: notation

Assuming I have a set $A$ of numbers, I'd like to mathematically notate a subset $B$, such that the cardinality of this subset is $x$ and its elements are the greatest $x$ elements of $A$. So, how can I mathematically notate this?
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One attempt:

Assuming $A$ has a maximal element, we can define a function to determine the set without the maximal element:
$$
f(A) = A \setminus \{ \max A \}
$$
Then 
$$
f^{x}(A) = (\underbrace{f \circ \dotsc \circ f}_{x})(A)
$$
is $A$ without the $x$ largest elements. Note: we did not provide any fail-safe that $A$ has $x$ largests elements.

Then
$$
B = A \setminus f^{x}(A)
$$

Another attempt:
$$
f(A, y) = (A \setminus \{ \max A \}, \max A) \\
B = \bigcup_{k=1}^x \pi_2(f^k(A, \cdot))
$$
where
$$
\pi_2(x, y) = y
$$
is the projection for the second argument and $\cdot$ stands for whatever value (it is ignored anyway).